# After modify table, I can't post data in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I edited my table structure, and I added field position. I changed my request file:

```
class StoreObject extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'mockup_view_port_id' => 'required|integer|exists:mockup_view_ports,id',
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'X' => 'required|integer',
        'Y' => 'required|integer',
        'width' => 'required|integer',
        'height' => 'required|integer',
        'position' => 'required|integer', //I added this line
    ];
  }
}
```

After this changes an error 500 is appearing. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'position' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `mockup_view_port_objects` (`mockup_view_port_id`, `name`, `X`, `Y`, `width`, `height`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, element 1, 5, 5, 30, 30, 2021-12-21 14:56:16, 2021-12-21 14:56:16))

```
public function store(StoreObject $request) : JsonResponse {
    return response()->json(MockupViewPortObject::create($request->validated()), 201);
}
```

The validation works fine. If I will forget sending position, the request validation doesn't pass. But if I send request with position validation pass, but there is sql error, and position becomes empty.

Comment: Have you added "position" to the $fillable array on your model?

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to maintain a list of `fillable` values, use `protected $guarded = ['id']` instead; all columns will be `fillable` by default, except for whatever ones you explicitly add here.